# Http_get function is undefined

Tags: php

When I try to do `http_get($url)` I attain an error: "`http_get is undefined`". I know I should import or enable a certain module **although** after searching I found absolutely nothing on this and even [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php) doesn't refer to anything.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: Just use [CURL](http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) and be happy... It even allows file uploads and stuff.

Comment: `pecl install pecl_http`

Comment: @TomášZato is CURL an alternative to pecl?

Comment: @diogocunga It allows for both POST and GET requests. It has actually so many cool options that you'll drown in them in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following contains access to the DLL files needed to use PECL on Windows http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/http/

unzipp it and copy the file `php_http.dll` in your PHP extension folder. Edit the php.ini file (c:\WINDOWS\php.ini unless you moved it somewhere else) and activate it

```
extension=php_http.dll
```